# NSMutableDictionary iVar Init Failure

Tags: ios5, nsmutabledictionary

Trying to populate a NSMutableDictionary (listContent) from a temp, local NSMutableDictionary (tmpDict) but the init of listContent seems to be failing and as such, the contents from tmpDict cannot be brought over. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Declarations in my .h file**

```
// .h
 NSMutableDictionary *listContent;
 ...
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *listContent;
```

**Implementation file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   //-- populating tmpDict here ....


  //Bring to life, this dictionary
  self.listContent = [NSMutableDictionary new];

 //--- self.listContent is still not alive   
  if(!self.listContent)
     NSLog(@"listContent is not alive, yet");

//populate self.listContent with contents of tmpDict        
[self.listContent addEntriesFromDictionary:tmpDict];

//--- self.listContent is still not alive 
 if(!self.listContent)
     NSLog(@"listContent is not alive, yet");


}
```

Comment: I think you'll be better off using `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` instead of `[NSMutableDictionary new]`.

Comment: Yep. Tried that. No change...

Answer (score 0):

Switching from LLDB to GBD fixed this. The problem was that my dictionary was being reported as nil by LLBD after it was initialized and populated with objects. Once I switched over to GBD, everything was correctly being initialized and hydrated.